# How to write test cases for custom ajax functionality using simpletest in drupal7

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript, testing

I am trying to write the test case for my custom ajax functionality in Drupal 7. I am firing the event on click in my `.js` file but the test case gets a fail.

In my `.tpl.php` template file I have the following code:

`<a href="javasctipt:void(0)" id="myFirstEvent">Click Here</a>`

In the Js file I am getting the event as follows:

```
$('#myFirstEvent').live('click', function())
$.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: Drupal.settings.basePath + '?q=mymodule/add',
        data: {page: page, sort: sort, order: order},
        dataType: 'text',
        error: function(request, status, error) {
            alert(status);
        },
        success: function(data, status, request) {
            /**Function definition goes here**/

}
```

In my custom.test file I have the following:

```
$edit = array();
$this>drupalGet("myform/add");
$this->drupalPost('myform/add', $edit, 'myFirstEvent');
$this->assertResponse(200, 'Success');
```

But I am not getting the success screen (Green Color) after I execute my test cases.

Comment: this [module](http://drupal.org/project/ajax_links_api) may help you

Comment: Serjas can figure our this problem?

Comment: first of all you have to wrap entire jquery code inside `(function($) { // your code here }) (jQuery);`

Comment: Serjas did you worked on (.test) file for functionality testing in drupal modules?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot test custom javascript with simpletest because it simply ignores them. Simpletest can simulate the ajax behavior (via xpath) only if you add that to the form with the #ajax property. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax

To test custom js you might want to have a look at Selenium.

Comment: Or JQuery Unit Tests: http://qunitjs.com/